# Understanding Source and Medium in Firebase Analytics

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm aiming to grasp the distinctions in the source and medium data we receive for users in Firebase. Specifically:

- Source: (Direct) vs Google Play
- Medium: (None) vs Organic

Could someone kindly assist me in understanding the significance of these different sources and mediums?